# Mounting exfat drive as read/write

Tags: 20.04, mount, exfat

I have ubuntu on my pc for half year right now. However recently I got annoyed by not enough space in my folder for files(ubuntu is on small 80 gb ide drive). So I partitioned my 750gb drive using exfat (drive has windows 10 on it) and mounted my partition. I was able to move files to it, change default download directory etc. The problem started, when I rebooted machine, and drive didn't mounted automatically. So I opened disk utility, checked custom mounting options, and checked auto mount. I rebooted pc, and drive mounted, but just for read. I've tried to edit /etc/fstab, but it did not help. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Has anyone had this issue before? I would really appreciated any help.

EDIT: this is my fstab line mounting drive `/dev/disk/by-uuid/9188-D2D0 /mnt/9188-D2D0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

Mikołaj

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re using (1) any errors you see in `/var/log/syslog` about mounting the ExFAT partition (2) the line in `/etc/fstab` that mounts the partition. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: the problem is, that there are no errors, partition just mounts as read-only

Comment: Exfat should be natively supported on 20.04 but maybe you don't have the right packages. Can you run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`. See if this makes a difference.

Comment: sadly it did not help

Comment: Can you edit the question with the details requested by @matigo

Comment: Are the permissions correct?  You can check this by command 'sudo nautilus'. Ensure user and groups have read/write permissions. Save. Reboot.

Comment: Did you run Windows with the exfat partition mounted? Do you use hibernation or fast startup in Windows? Please turn off fast startup, because it is a kind of hibernation and leaves file systems 'dirty', writing is not finished. - If this does not help, try to repair the drive in Windows, and if this does not help, unmount it and mount manually with specified ownership and permissions according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) that applies to all Microsoft file systems.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the permissions correct? You can check this by command 'sudo nautilus'. Ensure user and groups have read/write permissions. Save. Reboot. –

I thought, that I checked every possible setting, but it turned out, that I forgot about most basic thing, changing permission. I opened nautilus as sudo user, changed permission. Without rebooting I haven't seen any change, so I rebooted, and drive mounted like a charm. Thanks for help.